# Many "expected `)' before ';' token" errors

Tags: programming, sketch

As the title suggests, I have many "expected `)' before ';' token" errors. The issue is, I have this stuff in. So now I am confused, why am I getting this if the things are there.

I am new here and had an issue with adding code, so here is the pastebin link to it: http://pastebin.com/4WXxsXkB

And here is the the pastebin link to the error:
http://pastebin.com/QyehP86M

Does anyone understand how this could happen?

Comment: #defines do not have a ';' after them try removing these

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two #define statements at the top of your code

```
#define trigPin 3; 
#define echoPin 2;
```

The way `#define` works is that it replaces every instance of the name with everything after it on the line so `trigPin` is being replaced with `3;` as opposed to `3` as intended.

Fixing this should solve some of your problems.